# Few questions about Vue SSE(Server Sent Event)

Tags: vue.js, server-sent-events

I'm going to use SSE to implement real-time notifications.
Please look at my method and tell me what the problem is and how to solve it.

in vuex login action method

```
// SSE EvnetSource Connect
      let url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + "subscribe";
      let eventSource = new EventSource(url, {
        withCredentials: true
      });
      eventSource.addEventListener("notification", function (event) {
        console.log(event.data);
        commit('setNotification', event.data) // => set event's data to vuex 'notification' state as array
      });
```

and then

in top nav component's watch method

```
watch: {
  notification(val) {
    if(val) {
      const notiData = JSON.parse(val)
      if(notiData.id) {
        // show notification alert component 
        this.$notify("info filled", "notification", notiData.content, null, {
          duration: 7000,
          permanent: false
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

}

This is my current situation.

And this is my questions.

1. Currently, when logging in through vuex, I create an EventSource, but how to delete the EventSource when logging out? (EventSource is not defined globally, so I don't know how to approach it when logging out).
2. How to reconnect EventSource after page refresh? (I think main.js can handle it.)
3. Is there a way to put in Custom Header when creating EventSource?

Answer (score 3):

As any other event bus, `EventSource` needs to be unsubscribed when events shouldn't be received. This requires to keep a reference to listener function. If a listener uses Vuex context that is available inside an action, it should be defined inside login action and stored in a state:

```
  const notificationListener = (event) => {...};
  eventSource.addEventListener("notification", notificationListener);

  // can be moved to a mutation
  state._notificationEventSource = eventSource;
  state._notificationListener = notificationListener;
```

Inside logout action:

```
let { _notificationEventSource: eventSource, _notificationListener: notificationListener } = state;
eventSource.removeEventListener("notification", notificationListener);
```

It's no different when a page is initially loaded and reloaded.